# Cython Speed Boost vs. Usability

Tags: python, performance, cython

I just came across Cython, while I was looking out for ways to optimize Python code. I read various posts on Stack Overflow, the python wiki and read the article "General Rules for Optimization".

Cython is something which grasps my interest the most; instead of writing C-code for yourself, you can choose to have other data types in your python code itself.

Here is a silly test I tried,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# test.pyx
def test(value):
    for i in xrange(value):
    i**2
    if(i==1000000):
        print i

test(10000001)
```

$ time python test.pyx

```
real    0m16.774s 
user    0m16.745s
sys     0m0.024s
```

$ time cython test.pyx

```
real    0m0.513s 
user    0m0.196s 
sys     0m0.052s
```

Now, honestly, I'm dumbfounded. The code which I have used here is pure python code, and all I have changed is the interpreter. In this case, if the cython is this good, then why do people still use the traditional Python interpreter? Are there any reliability issues for Cython?

Comment: You are measuring the run-time of a Python script vs. the compile-time of some Cython code. That makes no sence.

Comment: As for your last remark: that's basically what Julia is trying to do: making an optimized low-level code translator in a coherent high-level machine language, and clearly showing this intention from the start so that it gets better traction even if it means that some high level features are lost in the way such as dynamic typing.

Comment: @SturlaMolden: Isn't this a test of Python interpret vs Cython copile and execute? If so it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Eddy No, because the Cython compile only needs to be done once, it can even be done ahead of time. Python bytecode interpret happens on each invocation, and similar to Cython bytecode compilation only need to be done once. Benchmarks therefore needs a burn-in round to get rid of these constant-time overheads, that happen on the first invocation.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The other answers have already explained how you were just compiling the Cython code, not executing it. However, I thought that you might want to know how much faster Cython can make your code. When I compiled the code you have (though I ran the function from from a different module) with [`distutils`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/distutils.html), I got very marginal speed gains over straight Python – about 1%. However, when I added a few small changes to your code:

```
def test(long long value):
    cdef long long i
    cdef long long z
    for i in xrange(value):
        z = i**2
        if(i==1000000):
            print i
        if z < i:
            print "yes"
```

and compiled it, I got the following times:

- **Pure Python code:** 20.4553578737 seconds
- **Cython code:** 0.199339860234 seconds

That’s a 100× speed-up. Not too shabby.

Comment: It possibly comes at the price of correctness. The Python code computes the correct value of `i ** 2`. The C code overflows for the majority of the numbers for which you perform the operation if you're compiling 32-bit code. (If it performs the operation at all. It's conceivable that your C compiler optimises out the operation altogether.) This probably isn't a fair comparison. You also haven't made it entirely clear what you're running, how you're running it, and what you're timing when you give those times.

Comment: Incidentally, this is the sort of thing I meant by "quirks". I almost provided the example of overflow as when Python code automatically performs checks that ensure correctness and such that would fail silently in C.

Comment: You're right. I thought about the overflow while I was doing it, but was lazy because I knew that it didn't really matter in this case. I'll fix it to use long longs.

Comment: @JustinPeel I have a [Cython post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944883/verifying-compatibility-in-compiling-extension-types-and-using-them-with-cdef) you may be able to provide insight on.

Comment: Good explaination. But how does it answer.the question? >>>If cython is this good, then why do people still use the traditional Python interpretor? Are there any reliability issues for Cython?

Answer (score 18):

Cython is not another interpreter. It generates c-extensions for python, from python(-like) code. `cython test.pyx` will only generate a 'test.c' file, which (once compiled) can be used by python just like a normal python library.

That means that you are only measuring the time it takes for cython to translate your python code to c, not how fast that version of your code runs.

Comment: Yea, for anyone who wishes that cython actually compiled and ran your program in one line, I created runcython (https://github.com/russell91/runcython). `runcython test.pyx` will have the semantics that the OP intended.

Answer (score 10):

- `cython test.pyx` doesn't actually run your program. The `cython` binary is for processing your Cython code into a Python extension module. You would have to import it in Python to run it.
- `#!/usr/bin/python` isn't the best shebang line for Python scripts. `#!/usr/bin/env python` is generally preferred, which runs whatever `python` would on the command line.

  - Cython `pyx` files probably shouldn't have a shebang line at all, except in the corner case they are valid Python programs.
- You have an IndentationError in the posted code.
- Using the traditional interpreter is simpler and more portable. Cython is reliable, but has its limitations and quirks. It might be compelling to use it tons more if it magically gave the speedups your timings make it look like it does, but it actually gives smaller ones. You'll have to start using Cython-specific features to use C features to see a lot of speedup.

Answer (score 9):

A big point that seems to be missing: Cython is not a strict superset of Python. There are some features that Python supports, but Cython does not. Most notably, generators and lambdas (but they are coming).

Comment: do you know if they came yet?

Answer (score 3):

- Biggest reason Cython is not that popular is that it lacks standalone (without python) executables.
- Lack of publicity. The developers seem to be academics more interested in Developing their Sage software, than a cutting edge language.
- Pitfalls encountered during development. One I encountered is lack of true thread support. Everything is wrapped up in a global interpreter lock, making it threadsafe, but disabling concurrency!

Comment: You can release the GIL when it is not needed. That is when you are not using the Python C API. In Cython this is written as "with nogil:", and you will get an error when releasing the GIL is unsafe. Python threads are native OS threads and will give you concurrency when the GIL is released. That is true for Python and Cython alike.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who wishes that cython actually compiled and ran your program in one line, I created runcython (http://github.com/russell91/runcython). `runcython test.pyx` will have the semantics that the OP intended

Comment: Link is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

As many of comments suggesting the time you have mentioned with cython is just time taken in converting .py file into .c file. That .c file will be big interms of memory. The advantage is that you can compile that .c file using C compiler also

I will give you one example :
if you have a python file we need to store as .pyx file. By running "**cython xyz.pyx**" it will create .c and .so files

Lets check in picture    [files created by cython command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7AoI.jpg)

The size also increases in my case it changed for **Bytes** to **Kb**

There is some specific method to compile the python code 
you can refer this links:

http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html
https://rajeshrinet.github.io/blog/2014/cython/

another thing i noticed is no where they mention the memory problems in cython
When i try to implement in my embedded project.I am facing lot of memory problems.

You can try pypy Where there is no need to put extra efforts to compile and the time also reduced in terms of compilation time

Refer the picture:
[compare time between python and pypy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Fxw.jpg)

Thank you..