# 64-bit integers in Cython

Tags: python, types, cython

I'm trying to interface a C++ library (pHash) with Python using Cython, but I have trouble with some of the types. The library functions use "unsigned long long" and I can't find a way to declare variables and parameters with this type. I searched for a list of the types that I can use with cdef but I found nothing. Can anyone point me to such a list (if it exists) or otherwise suggest a way to use 64 bit types in Cython? Thanks.

Comment: If I may ask -- did you succeed in calling pHash from Cython? And if so, is that code public in some form? I'm also trying to use Cython for pHash calls, and code samples such as yours would no doubt help with my wheel-reinvention (I've only used Cython to reimplement algorithms for speed; I'm not enough of a C hacker to handily call into 3rd-party libs without setting off a segfault avalanche). No pressure of course, and thanks either way.

Comment: Yes, I did. I haven't used the code for a while so I'm not sure about the state of the latest code, but you probably could use it as a start. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/7nCiTZFa. I've also found this simple wrapper: https://github.com/polachok/py-phash. It only contains image hashing though. And by the way, if you find the source code useful and are concerned about licensing, I'm releasing it in the public domain. Have fun!

Comment: Wow -- those links are both super handy, thanks very much. I appreciate the code sample -- it would have taken me quite a while to amass all of the facets of calling-convention nuance to figure out `(<ulong64*> ret[i].hash)[0]` and suchlike. Much obliged sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one of my answers using `unsigned long long` with cython

[Simple Python Challenge: Fastest Bitwise XOR on Data Buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119761/simple-python-challenge-fastest-bitwise-xor-on-data-buffers/2174000#2174000)

Answer (score 5):

I've been able to use both `unsigned long long` and `long long` just fine with cdef. See for instance my answer to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697275/cython-speed-boost-vs-usability). I just tried running the same code there with `unsigned long long` instead of `long long` and it worked just fine. Can you be more specific about what problems you are having with these types? Maybe you could post some source code that isn't working for you?

Comment: I tried once more and now everything is working. I still can't figure out what I did wrong. Thank you for your reply.