# Why there is a huge performance difference between these two codes in Python and Cython?

Tags: python, performance, cython

I encountered performance problems in Python, one of my friends suggest me using Cython
After searching more i found this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697275/cython-speed-boost-vs-usability)

Python:

```
def test(value):
    for i in xrange(value):
        z = i**2
        if(i==1000000):
            print i
        if z < i:
                print "yes"
test(10000001)
```

Cython:

```
def test(long long value):
    cdef long long i
    cdef long long z
    for i in xrange(value):
        z = i**2
        if(i==1000000):
            print i
        if z < i:
            print "yes"

test(10000001)
```

After i execute both codes, surprisingly i achieved 100x speedup by Cython

Why just by adding variable declarations this speedup achieved ??
Also i should mention the bellow code performance is the same as Python in Cython.

Cython:

```
def test(long long value):
    for i in xrange(value):
        z = i**2
        if(i==1000000):
            print i
        if z < i:
            print "yes"

test(10000001)
```

Comment: The Python version won't work with the `long long` still in the function argument declaration.

Comment: Why are you surprised at C-compiled code running a loop being faster?

Comment: Because of static-typing? http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html

Comment: Martijn Pieters, Fixed Python code

Comment: Martijn Pieters, The code in the third block also is a C-Compiled code but the performance is same as Python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is a language. CPython is an *bytecode compiler* and an *interpreter* for Python.

It will take some code:

```
for i in xrange(value):
    z = i**2
    if(i==1000000):
        print i
    if z < i:
        print "yes"
```

and give you "bytecode":

- load the iterator into the `for` loop and loop its contents into `i`
- load `i`, load `2`, run binary power, store `z`
- load `i`, load `1000000`, compare
- load `i`, print
- load `z`, load `i`, compare
- load `'yes'`, print
- finish

In full:

```
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              70 (to 73)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (xrange)
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (value)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                56 (to 72)
             16 STORE_NAME               2 (i)

  2          19 LOAD_NAME                2 (i)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
             25 BINARY_POWER        
             26 STORE_NAME               3 (z)

  3          29 LOAD_NAME                2 (i)
             32 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000000)
             35 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             38 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       49

  4          41 LOAD_NAME                2 (i)
             44 PRINT_ITEM          
             45 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             46 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 49)

  5     >>   49 LOAD_NAME                3 (z)
             52 LOAD_NAME                2 (i)
             55 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             58 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       13

  6          61 LOAD_CONST               2 ('yes')
             64 PRINT_ITEM          
             65 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             66 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
             69 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13

        >>   72 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   73 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             76 RETURN_VALUE
```

It's worth noting that in Python, an integer is an *instance* of the class `int` or `long`. This means that there is not only the number, but a *pointer* and another piece of informations saying what class it is *at least*. This makes a lot of overhead.

But it's also worth noting how `xrange` works.

`xrange` creates a class instance (`LOAD_NAME (xrange)`, `CALL_FUNCTION`) that can be iterated over by the `for`. The `for` will (basically) delegate to a function call on the iterator's `__iter__`. There is a function call *every loop*.

Further, every time you want to get or set the variable `z` or `i`, it has to look in the locals dictionary. This is really slow.

---

**Running pure Python-Code in Cython:**

When you run it in Cython (the third example in your question), it compiles to C. But all this C does is *tell* the CPython virtual machine what to do.

CPython alone: a guy reading from a book, and merticulously carrying out its functions.
CPython with Cython: a guy *shouting* instructions *to* the guy who merticulously carries out its functions.

It might be a tiny bit faster, but the slow part is still that CPython is slowly doing the work.

---

**Using *cythonized* code:**

What happens when you `cdef long long`, then?

- Cython knows that `xrange` is acting on a `long long`:

  - It knows the loop is valid (so it doesn't have to check that you gave it a `list` or somesuch)
  - It knows the loop won't overflow (because it's undefined if it does!)
  - It can therefore turn it into a C loop (`for (int index=0; index<copy_of_value; index++) { i = index; ... }`)
- This avoids the `int` and `long` classes, which have *a lot* of indirection overhead and type checking
- This avoids dictionary lookups. Things are always where you put them on the stack
- For example `i ** 2` is much simpler as the routine can be inlined (it's always a number, dude) and work directly on the integer and ignore overflow

So the result ends up being run mostly by C, and only goes to CPython for some cleanup stuff and the `print` calls.

---

Make sense?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks for your vivid examples!

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment: Your third solution is slower/as-slow-as-the-python-version because it lacks the static typing features that allow Cython to speed up your code. When you declare a variable as `long` f.e., Cython does not need to construct an "expensive" Python-Object, but may rely on C-Code completely. I'm not a Cython nor a Python expert, but I guess Python's object construction is the main bottleneck.

Comment: This seems right, but I remember reading about the way Python [pre-allocates blocks of integers](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/). Does it still do this? If so, does the static typing prevent this? It seems like if it's allocating a block of 40 empty integers regardless this cannot be the reason.

Comment: I do not think that just expense of creating python objects leads us to this poor performance, but sincerely i have no idea about this problem

Comment: I think it does not run in the Python/CPython VM, but is compiled C-Code (machine code), which simply runs faster than bytecode within the CPython VM. However, to get speed-improvements from Cython, one must declare the type of the variable (long) to get a speed-up. Otherwise, it will use the Python (dynamic-typed) object-creation mechanism, which are more resource-consuming (because it's dynamic & the byte-code will be interpreted on the fly, some type-checking is going on and so on). But that's just an educated guess ^^